# How do I update core to only include security patches?

Tags: 7, updating

I have a old Drupal 7 installation and I would like to update my Drupal 7 to the latest release, but I know for a fact that some of my custom module will break on the latest update.

All I want installed is the security patches up to the latest Drupal 7. How can this be done or is it even possible without much effort? Also where and how can I view what is being patched during an update of Drupal 7 core?

Comment: BY break, I assume you are mean that you have modules that don't work with the itok change?

Comment: Would like an equivalent question for D8, that gives a definitive answer like the accepted one here, at the moment, this answer looks like a good contender for that for D8: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/167925/1082

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you use Drush you can update **all security issues** with your site via (this is Core and 3rd party modules):
`drush up --security-only`

if you want to see what it will do, but not do any of the actual changes you can issue:
`drush up --security-only --simulate`

If you want an easy way to update Drupal Core to the newest release you can use a patch site such as:
http://fuerstnet.de/en/drupal-upgrade-easier

Comment: All true; you can also update projects one at a time via `drush up views`.  Test on a copy of your site, of course!

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the question.  I read it as applying just the security related patches and not bug-fixes or other enhancements that may be included with the same git tag as one marked as a security release.