# Unable to Update to latest core

Tags: 8, updating

Update from 8.5.0 to 8.5.1 is failing on one of my drupal instance.

```
>composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package symfony/debug (locked at v4.0.6, required as ^3.4.0)
 is satisfiable by symfony/debug[v4.0.6] but these conflict with your 
requirements or minimum-stability.
```

What does this mean? What should I do?

PS: Please find below some more related information

```
>composer outdated
consolidation/output-formatters       3.1.13       3.2.0
dflydev/dot-access-data               v1.1.0       v2.0.0
drupal/core                           8.5.0        8.5.1
drupal/metatag                        1.4.0        1.5.0
egulias/email-validator               1.2.14       2.1.3
guzzlehttp/guzzle                     6.3.0        6.3.2
nikic/php-parser                      v3.1.5       v4.0.1
psy/psysh                             v0.8.17      v0.8.18
symfony-cmf/routing                   1.4.1        2.0.3
symfony/config                        v3.4.6       v4.0.6
symfony/console                       v3.4.6       v4.0.6
symfony/dependency-injection          v3.4.6       v4.0.6
symfony/event-dispatcher              v3.4.6       v4.0.6
symfony/filesystem                    v3.4.6       v4.0.6
symfony/finder                        v3.4.6       v4.0.6
symfony/http-foundation               v3.4.6       v4.0.6
symfony/http-kernel                   v3.4.6       v4.0.6
symfony/process                       v3.4.6       v4.0.6
symfony/routing                       v3.4.6       v4.0.6
symfony/serializer                    v3.4.6       v4.0.6
symfony/translation                   v3.4.6       v4.0.6
symfony/validator                     v3.4.6       v4.0.6
symfony/var-dumper                    v3.4.6       v4.0.6
symfony/yaml                          v3.4.6       v4.0.6
twig/twig                             v1.35.2      v2.4.7
```

composer.json file:

```
    "name": "drupal/drupal",
    "description": "Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0+",
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.0.24",
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4",
        "drush/drush": "^9.2",
        "drupal/ctools": "^3.0",
        "drupal/devel": "^1.2",
        "drupal/ds": "^3.1",
        "drupal/conditional_fields": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/field_group": "^1.0",
        "drupal/filefield_paths": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/bootstrap_layouts": "^5.1",
        "drupal/page_manager": "^4.0@beta",
        "drupal/page_manager_ui": "^4.0@beta",
        "drupal/magnific_popup": "^1.3",
        "drupal/config_update": "^1.5",
        "drupal/config_update_ui": "^1.5",
        "drupal/duration_field": "^1.1",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.1",
        "drupal/token": "^1.1",
        "drupal/metatag": "^1.4",
        "drupal/bootstrap": "^3.10",
        "drupal/features": "^3.7",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^1.23",
        "drupal/linked_field": "^1.1",
        "drupal/core": "^8.5",
        "drupal/bootstrap_paragraphs": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/entity_reference_revisions": "^1.4",
        "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.2",
        "drupal/eva": "^1.3",
        "drupal/slick_views": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/yaml_editor": "^1.0"
    },
    "replace": {
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "autoloader-suffix": "Drupal8"
    },
    "extra": {
        "_readme": [
            "By default Drupal loads the autoloader from ./vendor/autoload.php.",
            "To change the autoloader you can edit ./autoload.php.",
            "This file specifies the packages.drupal.org repository.",
            "You can read more about this composer repository at:",
            "https://www.drupal.org/node/2718229"
        ],
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "core/composer.json"
            ],
           ],
            "recurse": false,
            "replace": false,
            "merge-extra": false
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "drush/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ],
            "modules/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-module"
            ],
            "themes/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-theme"
            ]
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\": "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Composer"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::preAutoloadDump",
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::ensureHtaccess"
        ],
        "post-package-install": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
        "post-package-update": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup"
    },
    "repositories": {
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        "drupal": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also add your composer.json file?

Comment: Added composer.json to the log

Comment: Anybody, any suggestions? I am stuck, I don't want to do the manual upgrade...

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/258940/how-do-i-update-core-to-8-5, you have basically the same problem as far as I see, you are mixing drupal/drupal and drupal/core

Comment: Thanks @Berdir! Looks like I need to start from drupal-project as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the composer.lock file and try

```
composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies
```

Comment: Not working! 
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package symfony/debug (installed at v4.0.6, required as ^3.4.0) is satisfiable by symfony/debug[v4.0.6] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Comment: Can you try this `composer update --with-dependencies drupal/core:~8.5 symfony/class-loader:~3.2.13 drush/drush:~9.@dev`

Comment: where  `"drupal/core": "^8.x",` is written in composer.json file. I think you should write it in `require { "drupal/core": "^8.x", }` part.

Comment: Composer.json is added to the quesiton. The above command still showing error.