# How to update 8.0.x to 8.1.x with composer?

Tags: 8, composer

This is excerpt from my composer.json file (trimmed for readability). It was created by running `composer create-project drupal/drupal my_site_name 8.0.*` as described on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/2404989):

```
{
  "name": "drupal/drupal",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.0.21",
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "replace": {
    "drupal/core": "~8.0"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true,
  "extra": {
    "merge-plugin": {
      "include": [
        "core/composer.json"
      ],
      "recurse": false,
      "replace": false,
      "merge-extra": false
    }
  }
}
```

1. If I just do `composer update` - core is not updated, only packages inside `vendor` dir.
2. If in addition to the above, I update my `composer.json` file and replace core version with `~8.1` - still core not affected.

The only thing that worked for me was to:

1. Remove `core` dir, `vendor` and `composer.lock`.
2. Edit `composer.json` and:

   1. Remove `replace` section.
   2. Add `"drupal/core": "~8.1"` to `require` section.
3. Run `composer install`.

That worked however every installed package complained that:

> Class Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer is not autoloadable, can not call post-package-install script

So I'm not sure if the whole process completed flawlessly. Also removing `core` directory seems like a desperate move.

What is the recommended procedure of updating core to the next minor version with composer (for example 8.0 => 8.1)?
Note that I am *not using* [drupal-composer](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project) as suggested in [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/167925/5982).

## Update 1

After trying to use `composer require --update-with-dependencies "drupal/core:8.1.*"` I got no results:

```
$ composer create-project drupal/drupal my_site_name 8.0.*
Installing drupal/drupal (8.0.6)
  - Installing drupal/drupal (8.0.6)
    Cloning c5afca05cde0c94ef4d7aff5b078be27024670d2

Created project in my_site_name
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::preAutoloadDump
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::ensureHtaccess
Do you want to remove the existing VCS (.git, .svn..) history? [Y,n]? Y
$ cd my_site_name/
$ composer require --update-with-dependencies "drupal/core:8.1.*"
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::preAutoloadDump
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::ensureHtaccess
```

I'm using composer version `1.1-dev`.

Comment: I think if you want to use Composer to update core, then you should follow drupal-composer. Otherwise, use Git or drush and composer update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see, you directly get `drupal/drupal`. I don't think that's actually supported, you still get a vendor folder from git and the `composer.json` isn't properly set up. I'm using composer command from [this site](http://bojanz.wordpress.com/2015/09/18/d8-composer-definitive-intro):

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev myproject --stability dev --no-interaction
```

Regarding update, the trick seems to be the following argument to composer require:

```
composer require --update-with-dependencies "drupal/core:8.1.*"
```

That updated drupal/core and all dependencies it has.

Comment: This command added `drupal/core:8.1.*` to `composer.json` file inside require section and returned _Nothing to install or update_. After that when I ran `composer update` only `vendor` dir got updated, but not core.

Comment: I tested this, it worked perfectly fine for me for updating from a drupal-project on 8.0.6 to 8.1.0-rc1. Maybe your previous testing messed something up. try it on a clean install and if that works, try to figure out what you already have changed and what's confusing it.

Comment: That's what I'm doing - I'm testing this with clean install. Please have a look at my update to the question. I've pasted commands and output that I got.

Comment: I see, you directly get drupal/drupal. I don't think that's actually supported, you still get a vendor folder from git and the composer.json isn't properly set up. I'm using "composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev myproject --stability dev --no-interaction" from https://bojanz.wordpress.com/2015/09/18/d8-composer-definitive-intro/. Works fine there.

Comment: Well, I'm using a method provided on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/2404989). I expected that to be more accurate :)

Comment: See the comments, for example "This entire page needs a full rewrite. My blog post can be used as a source of content." from @bojanz ;)

Comment: Crap. `drupal-composer` solution messes up directory structure by putting things into web subdirectory. And I have projects and git repos already set up :( So what is the actual and official way of handling drupal via composer? Bojanz's blog post? I don't want to run into this mess again when going for `drupal-composer`.

Comment: The web folder becomes the public folder, you just need to move things around so that the virtual host or whatever you use points to that folder. But yes, existing projects and git history will have to change.

Comment: This answer didn't work for me. e.g. `- drupal/entity 8.0.1 requires drupal/system <8.1.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.0.6, 8.0.x-dev].` causing `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.` So I had to require each of 8.1.0's dependencies in turn just the same as without the `--update-with-dependencies` option. Painful.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. drupal/entity is not a dependency of drupal/core, it depends on it. So a combination of those two with --update-with-dependencies, or maybe even only drupal/entity should work.

Comment: Yes, the answer did work eventually. Can't explain what changed to allow this /prevent it before. Bit of s mystery but resolved now.