# Why doesn't core get updated to 8.5?

Tags: updating, composer

I am trying to update via Composer following what reported in [Update core via Composer](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-via-composer), but when I do `composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies`, I get the following output.

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Nothing to install or update
>   Generating autoload files

I checked /admin/report/updates, and I can see that Drupal 8.5 is available. The content of composer.json is the following.

```
    "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    }
]
```

Why isn't Composer updating core?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! In order to giving you an answer, please add the version restrictions of your Drupal core from the `composer.json`'s `require` section to the question. (Should look like e.g. `"drupal/core": "^8.5"`) - You may as well check out this question/answer first: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/167922/what-is-the-correct-composer-based-core-update-workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies` doesn't work, verify the *composer.json* file contains these lines and remove them. (XX equals anything.)

```json
"replace": {
    "drupal/core": "~8.XX"
}
```

In any case, run `composer require drupal/core:~8.5.1`, even if the *composer.json* file did not contain those lines.

If that fails, try my last ditch method.

- Remove the *core* and *vendor* folders

  ```bash
  sudo rm -rf core vendor
  ```
- Clear the Composer cache

  ```bash
  composer clearcache
  ```
- Run `composer require drupal/core:~8.5.1`

Don't forget to make a backup first, if you haven't already.

Comment: After running your code, removing core & vendor, clearing composer cache, I ran composer require and got some errors. I followed [https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2943546](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2943546) and ran composer update . Everything downloaded, and got things running again thank!

Comment: My pleasure! And thanks for your comment outlining what other steps you took, it will help others that stumble on this page.