# Updating core from 8.5.4 to 8.5.6

Tags: composer

I'm trying to update Drupal core to lasted version with `composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies`. I followed the instructions given on [Update core via Composer](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-via-composer), but Composer claims there is nothing to install or update. It also prints the following message.

> Package "drupal/core" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.

Comment: Is drupal/core listed in the require section your composer.json file?

Comment: Can you include the contents of your composer.json file in your question?

Comment: Also, make sure you're within the correct directory. Running the above command within the Drupal root is of no good as it's part of the `drupal/core` package itself. The mentioned instructions refer to a composer scaffold around the Drupal root (usually one folder above) that have `drupal/core` as dependency.

Comment: You may find my answer to this similar question helpful https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/259592/why-doesnt-core-get-updated-to-8-5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1,
in file `composer.json` add

```
"require": {
"drupal/core": "~8.5"
}
```

Remove line

```
"replace": {
    "drupal/core": "^8.5"
}
```

remote folder `vendor`
remove file `composer.log`

alter run

```
composer update --with-dependencies
```

Comment: On its own, wouldn't this install Drupal core into the `vendor/drupal/core` folder? I'd expect you need at the very least to add `"extra": { "installer-paths": { "./core": ["type:drupal-core"] }}` to make it end up in the right place...